# No route matches [DELETE] "/msg.5"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

there is my routes.rb

```
     resources :msgs, only: [:create, :destroy, :new]
     resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
     resources :posts, only: [:show, :create, :destroy, :new]
```

and there is rake routes

```
    ![routes][1]


     msgs_path  POST                /msgs(.:format)     msgs#create
     new_msg_path         GET   /msgs/new(.:format)     msgs#new
                         DELETE /msgs/:id(.:format)     msgs#destroy
     sessions_path          POS /sessions(.:format)     sessions#create
     new_session_path   GET /sessions/new(.:format)     sessions#new
     session_path    DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)     sessions#destroy
     posts_path              POST  /posts(.:format)     posts#create
     new_post_path       GET   /posts/new(.:format)     posts#new
     post_path           GET   /posts/:id(.:format)     posts#show
                      DELETE   /posts/:id(.:format)     posts#destroy
```

Everytime im trying to delete message,i get No route matches [DELETE] "/msg.5" i dont know why,but resource msgs has msgs#new and msgs#destroy in one path(new_msgs_path),while resource posts has separate url for delete and onether for new actions,guess problem in this,but i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: The route should be `/msgs/5`. Show us the link.

Comment: sorry,something wrong with img,i added text format

Comment: The routes are fine, it's how you generate the delete link that isn't.

Comment: then whats the problem?there delete method from msgs_controller.rb
     
      def destroy
    @msg=(Msg.find(params[:id])).delete
    redirect_to :back
      end

Comment: Post the code for the **link** you click to delete the message.

Comment: `<% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(@user) %>
   | <%= link_to "Delete", msg, method: :delete, data:    {confirm: "Are u sure?"} %>
 <% end %>`

Comment: Well, actually you're right. The link is good. Seems like there's an issue with your routes. It should be `msgs_path  DELETE /msgs/:id(.:format)     msgs#destroy`. Not sure what's wrong just looking at your routes.

Comment: what im need to attach?

Comment: I'm not sure. Try to clean up your routes. Try simplifying them to debug why the routes are not as intended (remove the :only etc)